# How to use fiscal calendar in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables "Fiscal_calendar" and "Sales". The 2 tables do not link together. I want to be able to write a query that calculates the total sales made a in a week according to the fiscal calendar. Is this possible? Our fiscal calendar starts from December 1st and every month end falls on a friday.

Any help would be appreciated.

Fiscal_calendar

```
Period   Period1_StartDate   Period1_EndDate   Period2_StartDate   Period2_EndDate...........
2018        01/12/2017          29/12/2017     30/01/2018          26/01/2018 


Sales
Sales_order_no   Amount   Date        Customer
111              20453    03/12/2017  abc
112              23154    04/12/2017  bbb
113              20201    10/12/2017  ddd
114              39012    11/12/2017  ccc
115              11111    18/12/2017  eee
116              22222    25/12/2017  uuu
```

So there are 4 weeks between Period 1 startdate and enddate. And the first 2 sales fall under week 1. So total sales for Week 1 would be 43607

OUTPUT

```
WEEK      Total_Sales
W1        43607
W2        59213
W3        11111
W4        22222
```

Comment: How many period startDate columns are there?  13?  *(Up to `period13_startDate, period13_endDate`?)*

Comment: If possible, I'd denormalize the fiscal_calendar to  be like: year, periodnumber, startdate, enddate. That will make the query alot easier!

Comment: @MatBailie yes,13

Comment: @mikeS - infact the majority of my answer is just normalising that mosnter, just so the rest of it is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two uses of `CROSS APPLY` to fix *(normalise)* the fiscal calendar table in to something useful, then a simple `GROUP BY`.

The `WHERE` clause picks the row from the fiscal calendar, that the period or week *(or whatever)* from the derived views.

The `LEFT JOIN` is in case of no sales in that week.

The `ON` clause looks at the fiscal calendar AND the week derived view, just in case the derived view describes a week that's not really in that year.

```
SELECT
  p.year_id,
  p.period_id,
  w.week_id,
  SUM(s.amount)   AS total_amount
FROM
  fiscal_calendar    c
CROSS APPLY
(
            SELECT period,  1,  period1_startDate,  period1_endDate
  UNION ALL SELECT period,  2,  period2_startDate,  period2_endDate
  ..
  UNION ALL SELECT period, 13, period13_startDate, period13_endDate
)
  AS p(year_id, period_id, startDate, endDate)
CROSS APPLY
(
            SELECT 1, DATEADD(d,  0, startDate), DATEADD(d,  6, startDate)
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATEADD(d,  7, startDate), DATEADD(d, 13, startDate)
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATEADD(d, 14, startDate), DATEADD(d, 20, startDate)
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, DATEADD(d, 21, startDate), DATEADD(d, 27, startDate)
)
  AS w(week_id, startDate, endDate)
LEFT JOIN
  sales              s
    ON  s.date BETWEEN c.period1_startdate AND c.period13_enddate
    AND s.date BETWEEN w.startDate         AND w.endDate
WHERE
      p.year_id   = 2018
  AND p.period_id = 1
GROUP BY
  p.year_id,
  p.period_id,
  w.week_id
```

Answer (score 1):

`UNPIVOT` is a useful TSQL operator to use when normalizing data.  Basically it takes a row and makes new rows - one for each column specified in a list of columns.

In the case below I unpivot on the PeriodX_StartDate columns.  I originally did two unpivots, the other on PeriodX_EndDate.  The end date was unnecessary, but in case you're wondering how I joined the two unpivots:  I used a cross apply to generate a key for each week and had a predicate that tested if they were equal.  Without the predicate you get a Cartesian product.

To generate the weeks I used a CROSS APPLY that is very similar to the one in @MatBailie's answer, except I avoided the unions by generating a set of arguments for each week that are passed into functions that generate the dates.

```
WITH normalizedCal AS (
    SELECT [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey, StartDate, CutoffDate
    FROM fiscal_calendar cal
    UNPIVOT (
        MonthStart FOR StartKey IN (Period1_StartDate, Period2_StartDate, ..., PeriodN_StartDate)
    ) AS startInfo
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 'WK' + CAST((StartIndex / 7) + 1 AS char(1)) [WeekKey]
            , DATEADD(day, startIndex, MonthStart) [StartDate]
            , DATEADD(day, EndIndex, MonthStart) [CutoffDate]
        FROM ( 
            VALUES ( 0, 7 ), ( 7, 14 ), ( 14, 21 ), ( 21, 28 )
        ) rangeValues ( StartIndex, EndIndex )
    ) weekInfo 
)
SELECT [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey, COALESCE(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) [Total_Sales]
FROM normalizedCal nc
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.Date >= nc.StartDate AND sales.Date < nc.CutoffDate
GROUP BY [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey
ORDER BY [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey
```

Working Example with sample data:

```
WITH normalizedCal AS (
    SELECT [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey, StartDate, CutoffDate
    FROM (
        VALUES (2018, '2017-12-01', '2017-12-29', '2017-12-30', '2018-01-26')
    ) cal ([Period],   Period1_StartDate,   Period1_EndDate, Period2_StartDate, Period2_EndDate)
    UNPIVOT (
        MonthStart FOR StartKey IN (Period1_StartDate, Period2_StartDate)
    ) AS startInfo
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 'WK' + CAST((StartIndex / 7) + 1 AS char(1)) [WeekKey]
            , DATEADD(day, startIndex, MonthStart) [StartDate]
            , DATEADD(day, EndIndex, MonthStart) [CutoffDate]
        FROM ( 
            VALUES ( 0, 7 ), ( 7, 14 ), ( 14, 21 ), ( 21, 28 )
        ) rangeValues ( StartIndex, EndIndex )
    ) weekInfo 
),
sales AS (
    SELECT [Sales_order_no],[Amount], CAST([Date] as DATE) [Date],[Customer]
    FROM (VALUES 
        (111, 20453, '2017-12-03', N'abc'),
        (112, 23154, '2017-12-04', N'bbb'),
        (113, 20201, '2017-12-10', N'ddd'),
        (114, 39012, '2017-12-11', N'ccc'),
        (115, 11111, '2017-12-18', N'eee'),
        (116, 22222, '2017-12-25', N'uuu')
    ) [salessrc] ( [Sales_order_no],[Amount],[Date],[Customer])
)
SELECT [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey, COALESCE(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) [Total_Sales]
FROM normalizedCal nc
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.Date >= nc.StartDate AND sales.Date < nc.CutoffDate
GROUP BY [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey
ORDER BY [Period], MonthStart, WeekKey
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your provided example, You could do something like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
    [YEAR]  = YEAR([Date]),
    [MONTH] = MONTH([Date]),
    [WEEK] = DATEPART(week, [Date]) - DATEPART(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)),
    SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY  YEAR([Date]), DATEPART(week, [Date]) - DATEPART(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0))+ 1) AS TotalSales
FROM Sales
)D 
GROUP BY 
    [YEAR], 
    [MONTH], 
    [WEEK], 
    TotalSales
```

this will give you the same results that you've provided in your example, however, since we don't know how your Fiscal_calendar is configured you will need to see is it a mandatory to link it with it or not.